# Quadratic equation , modulus

Tags: quadratic-forms

If $a,b,c$ are three distinct positive real numbers, then the number of roots of:
$$ax^2+2b|x|-c=0$$

Please be very specific with the answer. The answer is $2$ but I think it should be $4$ because even if there are negative values of $x$ they will become $+ve$.

Comment: That image is (nearly) unreadable. Please take the time to edit your question so that it includes the mathematics directly. Use the proper math formatting this site makes available: https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Math.SE. I'd recommend you to learn a bit of LaTeX to improve the readability. Also, use proper English.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for $x\geq 0$ we have to solve $$ax^2+2bx-c=0$$
the Solutions are $$x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{a}\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{c}{a}}$$
and if $x<0$ you have to solve $$ax^2-2bx-c=0$$
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{b}{a}\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{c}{a}}$$
in both case you will get the not the same Solutions

Comment: In the second case where it is -2bx when we apply the quad formula then it will be -(-2b) which will make it +2b . So both cannot be same

Comment: thx, i have corrected it

Comment: So if in both cases roots are different so the the number of real roots should be 4 but y is the answer 2

Comment: thus your printed answer is wrong

Comment: Play thank you for your help , I have posted another question. If you have time please look into it . Thank you

Comment: ok today here in Germany is a free day i will do what i can

Comment: The solution with $-$ has to be discarded in the first case, as the solution with $+$ in the second.

Comment: @N74 I can't see why: in both cases the discriminant is positive and thus there are two different roots in each case.

Comment: @DonAntonio but for the first case we supposed $x>0$ and the solution with $-$ would be negative, as all the constants are positive. Thus, this solution leads to a contradiction and must be excluded. The same is valid for the other solution.

Comment: @N74 Great point, thanks.